# Array method returning Array, only first value?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, methods

I am trying to get column data from sqlLite DB and put that data into an array method and then call the method and display the data, for some reason I am only getting the first variable in my column, help please!!!!

-Yes there are more variables in that column

```
    public String[] getScore01() {

    String[] column1 = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column1, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String[] result = {};

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        String[] result1 = { "" + c.getString(iName) };

        result = result1.clone();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and here we call the method and get the data set it to an array...

```
        Database info = new Database(this);

    info.open();
    String[] data = info.getScore01().clone();
    info.close();
```

setting the textview tvVVTEST to data[0] works, but setting it to data[1] or anything else fails why???

```
        tvVVTEST.setText("" + data[0]); //works
      //tvVVTEST.setText("" + data[1]); // Does Not Work
```

Comment: In that for loop, print result1[0] and see what's stored in each iteration, and you will know exactly what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
info.open();
String[] data = info.getScore01().clone();
info.close();
```

No need to call like this. Change this to

```
info.open();
String[] data = info.getScore01();
info.close();
```

And you have declared result two times.Second make sure that array value will insert on new position everytime.Otherwise it will over write and you will get only one value

**Edited**
changes inside loop to

```
where you declare String [] result, Change to String []result=new String[c.getCount()];
 int i=0;
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

    result1[i] = c.getString(iName);
    i++;
}
return result;
```

Comment: I have edited check it once.And if it solved problem mark it as answer

Answer (score 2):

Look at this loop:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

    String[] result1 = { "" + c.getString(iName) };

    result = result1.clone();
}
return result;
```

You're only ever setting `result1` to a single element array, and then `result` to a clone of that array. Therefore `result` will only ever refer to a single-element array. I suggest you use a `List<String>` instead:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    results.add(c.getString(iName));
}
return results;
```

(Change your method to declare that it returns a `List<String>` as well.)

You should then be able to use

```
List<String> data = info.getScore01();
tvVVTest.setText(data.get(1)); // Assuming there *is* a second element
```

By the way, you seem to be using `"" + x` wherever you want a string. That's a bad idea even when `x` *isn't* a string - use `String.valueOf(x)` instead - but it's even worse when `x` *is* a string.

You also don't need to be cloning arrays (or lists) all over the place. Oh, and you should put the `info.close()` method in a finally block, so that you close the database even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: This works but the problem is that I need an Array (because i'am putting the array that iam getting in a listview) I guess I could convert the list array data to a array ?

Comment: @FC_Inter_Fan: Do you *really* need to put it in as an array rather than as a list? If so, you can call `list.toArray(new String[0])` - but I'd try to avoid using the array directly if you possibly can.

Comment: I needed an array to do this:   

lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, data, number);
  list.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
  lviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Trying to have the data from 2 different columns in a database display in a arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
System.out.println(data.length);
```

If its one then you probably only have one element in your array.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use that for() syntax that news to me. What happens if you use a while loop instead?

```
while( c.moveToNext() ) {
```

Comment: returns 1 element only again ;/

Comment: What do you think is wrong with that `for` syntax? Looks perfectly normal to me: initialization, condition, post-iteration-action.